# C++ No members available in a template class

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement the hash table class, but when I try to access the STL list member functions and iterator in the Hash_Table class, visual studio says no members available. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#define INIT_SIZE 11

using namespace std;

template<typename KEY_TYPE, typename VALUE_TYPE>
class Hash_Table
{
public:
typedef pair<const KEY_TYPE, VALUE_TYPE> Entry_Type;

// Constructor 
Hash_Table(const int size = INIT_SIZE)
{
    myTable.resize(size);
}

// HashCode() function for calculating hash code of a specified key;
int HashCode(const KEY_TYPE& key)
{
    int index = hash<KEY_TYPE>(key) % myTable.size();

    return index; 
}

void Insert (const Entry_Type& value)
{

}

// Index operator
Entry_Type& operator [] (const KEY_TYPE& key)
{
    typename list<Entry_Type>::     ;//no members available
            myTable[0].                    ; //no members available
}

void Rehash ();

private:
// the table
vector<list<Entry_Type>> myTable; 
};
```

Can anyone tell me why it happens? Thank you so much!

Comment: `std::list` is a standard container that doesn't have a `myTable` symbol. Why aren't you simply accessing it as `myTable` like in your other methods?

Comment: @0x499602D2: The way I read it, I think he means that he doesn't get any intellisense in either of the two scenarios given, not that that's his exact code.

Comment: @StuartGolodetz exactly, and thanks for reminding.